# Gulp start Server

Tags: javascript, express, server, gulp

Can any one help me with a gulp file?

I want to start my express server when i run `gulp dev`. The express server starts in my `app.js` file. I tried to modify the `app.js` file but that causes an error.

How do i implement that ?

```
var gulp = require('gulp')
var sass = require('gulp-sass')
var header = require('gulp-header')
var cleanCSS = require('gulp-clean-css')
var rename = require('gulp-rename')
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify')
var pkg = require('./package.json')
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create()
var server = require('gulp-develop-server')

var express = require('express')
var app = express()


 // Copy third party libraries from /node_modules into /vendor
 gulp.task('vendor', function () {
 // Bootstrap
 gulp.src([
'./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/**/*',
'!./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-grid*',
'!./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-reboot*'
 ])
.pipe(gulp.dest('./vendor/bootstrap'))

 // Font Awesome
gulp.src([
'./node_modules/font-awesome/**/*',
'!./node_modules/font-awesome/{less,less/*}',
'!./node_modules/font-awesome/{scss,scss/*}',
'!./node_modules/font-awesome/.*',
'!./node_modules/font-awesome/*.{txt,json,md}'
 ])
.pipe(gulp.dest('./vendor/font-awesome'))

 // jQuery
  gulp.src([
'./node_modules/jquery/dist/*',
'!./node_modules/jquery/dist/core.js'
  ])
.pipe(gulp.dest('./vendor/jquery'))

 // jQuery Easing
 gulp.src([
'./node_modules/jquery.easing/*.js'
])
.pipe(gulp.dest('./vendor/jquery-easing'))

// Simple Line Icons
gulp.src([
'./node_modules/simple-line-icons/fonts/**'
])
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./vendor/simple-line-icons/fonts'))

 gulp.src([
'./node_modules/simple-line-icons/css/**'
     ])
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./vendor/simple-line-icons/css'))
   })

// Compile SCSS
gulp.task('css:compile', function () {
return gulp.src('./scss/**/*.scss')
.pipe(sass.sync({
  outputStyle: 'expanded'
  }).on('error', sass.logError))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./css'))
 })

    // Minify CSS
   gulp.task('css:minify', ['css:compile'], function () {
  return gulp.src([
  './css/*.css',
  '!./css/*.min.css'
 ])
.pipe(cleanCSS())
.pipe(rename({
  suffix: '.min'
}))
.pipe(gulp.dest('./css'))
.pipe(browserSync.stream())
})

// CSS
gulp.task('css', ['css:compile', 'css:minify'])

// Minify JavaScript
gulp.task('js:minify', function () {
return gulp.src([
'./js/*.js',
'!./js/*.min.js'
])
.pipe(uglify())
.pipe(rename({
  suffix: '.min'
}))
.pipe(gulp.dest('./js'))
.pipe(browserSync.stream())
})

// JS
gulp.task('js', ['js:minify'])

// Default task
gulp.task('default', ['css', 'js', 'vendor'])

gulp.task('express', function () {
app.use(express.static(__dirname))
app.listen(6006, '0.0.0.0') // <- CHANGE PORT NUMBER TO PREFERRED 
CHOICE
 })
        // Configure the browserSync task
   gulp.task('browserSync', function () {
   browserSync.init({
  server: {
    baseDir: './'
   }
  })
})

// Dev task
 gulp.task('dev', ['express', 'css', 'js', 'browserSync'], function () {
gulp.watch('./scss/*.scss', ['css'])
gulp.watch('./js/*.js', ['js'])
gulp.watch('./*.html', browserSync.reload)
})
```

Comment: What is the error message you are receiving?